# How to get a list of all subdomains for a particular site

Tags: ruby, dns, subdomain

How do I find a list of all subdomains for a particular site using ruby

Comment: While it's technically possible to obtain DNS zone information, don't forget that an application which uses wildcard domains wouldn't suit that approach. It might help to explain what problem you are trying to solve, perhaps it is for a particular site or application?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for all domains, but many allow a DNS zone transfer. You'll need Net::DNS for it. The following code should get you started:

```
require 'Net\DNS'

res = Net::DNS::Resolver.new
res.tcp_timeout(10)
zone = res.axfr('example.com')

if (zone)
    zone.each do | rr |
        print rr.inspect
else
    print 'Zone transfer failed: ', res.errorstring, "\n"
end
```

Comment: not working getting the following errorWARN -- : AXFR query, switching to TCP
ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with nil failed